# How to enable ? feature to substitute unwrap in rust?

Tags: rust

Consider the following example

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader, Result};

fn main() {

    let file = File::open("myfile.txt")?; // This doesn't work
    let file = File::open("myfile.txt").unwrap();  // this works
    for line in BufReader::new(file).lines() {
        println!("{}", line.unwrap());
    }
}
```

using `rustc 1.33.0 (2aa4c46cf 2019-02-28)`

I am trying to use `?` to substitute unwrap, but it seems like I always get `^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot use the`?`operator in a function that returns`()
 , can someone point me a direction?

Thanks

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html#propagating-errors, https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html#the--operator-can-only-be-used-in-functions-that-return-result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `?` operator only works inside functions that return `Result<T, E>`, since `expr?` is essentially the same as:

```
match expr {
  Ok(value) => value,
  Err(err) => return Err(err),
}
```

You can modify your `main()` function to return a result though. Using `Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>>` will allow you to use `?` on any standard error type that implements the `Error` trait:

```
use std::error::Error;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader};

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let file = File::open("myfile.txt")?; // this will now work
    for line in BufReader::new(file).lines() {
        println!("{}", line?);
    }

    // finally, we need to end with Ok(()) since we no longer have
    // the default return type ()
    Ok(())
}
```